# Expectation of a random variable with respect to joint distribution vs. marginal distribution

Tags: calculus, integration, proof-verification, random-variables, expectation

Denote the joint distribution of random variables $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$ by $p(\mathbf{x})=p(x_1, x_2, ..., x_n)$, and marginal distribution of $X_i$ by $p(x_i)$.

Can I write $\mathbb{E}_{p(\mathbf{x})}[X_i] = \mathbb{E}_{p(x_i)}[X_i] $? That is, dropping the irrelevant $X_2,...X_n$ in the original joint distribution $p(x_1, x_2, ..., x_n)$ over which the expectation is taken?

My rationale is (for the sake of argument let $i=1$):
$$\mathbb{E}_{p(\mathbf{x})}[X_1]
=\int... \int x_1 p(x_1,...,x_n) dx_1 dx_2...dx_n \\
=\int (\int... \int x_1 p(x_1,...,x_n) dx_2...dx_n) dx_1\\
=\int x_1 (\int... \int p(x_1,...,x_n) dx_2...dx_n) dx_1 \\
=\int x_1 p(x_1) dx_1  = \mathbb{E}_{p(x_i)}[X_1]$$

where the second equality (switching the order of integration) assumes Fubini's theorem applies (say I'm working with a multivariate Gaussian distribution).

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes this is OK. The expected value of $X_i$ can always be considered wrt its own distribution.